# Independant Disks

Tags: vmware-vsphere

Quick question...

If the option for Independant disks is selected, and made persistent, does thsi now mean I cannot take snapshots of the disk?

Someone has changed the deselected options to delected, so it is now independant and persistent, and I do not know why they would do that? One claim was "performance"?? But there was no prevoious snapshots on the datastore for the VM??

thanks

Answer (score 2):

An Independent persistent disk is a disk that is specifically excluded from Snapshots but otherwise behaves as you would expect. An Independent nonpersistent disk is transient in nature - changes made to the disk are lost when the VM is rebooted.

There is a performance recommendation that says to use independent persistent disks for heavy workload VM's but that really is just to ensure that the overhead associated with snapshotting  that disk is eliminated, if the machine has never been and isn't going to be snapshotted then I don't think it makes any measurable difference other than that.

The only difference it should make is that the disk in question will now never be included in snapshots.

Comment: Exactly the right answer.